# Java 1.7 + JSCH: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm

Tags: java, java-7, sftp, jsch, jce

I'm trying to use [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to upload a file to a remote [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) share. Every time I attempt to connect to the share from within my code, I get an exception that looks something like this:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:558) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.51.jar:na]
```

I've seen [posts that describe this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404371/java8-jcraft-key-is-too-long-for-this-algorithm) when upgrading to Java 8, but we're still on Java 7, and I don't know enough about Java's cryptography support to know if that matters.

Some people suggest installing JCE (Java Cryptography Extensions) to solve this problem, so I gave it a shot, but I still get the same error after copying the appropriate jar files into the /libs/security directory and restarting the application. We confirmed that JCE was installed by executing [this script](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/message/32660306/) and noting that the exception was not thrown.

I also tried connecting to the remote SFTP share from the terminal using the `sftp` command in verbose mode. Here's what I got:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXXXXXXXXXXXX [XXXXXXXXXXXX] port XX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 3.2.9 SSH Secure Shell
debug1: no match: 3.2.9 SSH Secure Shell
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" from file "/Users/XXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,twofish128-cbc,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,twofish128-cbc,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 122/256
debug2: bits set: 496/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug1: Server host key: DSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" from file "/Users/XXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "XXXXXXXXXXXX" from file "/Users/XXXXX/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
    The authenticity of host 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXX)' can't be established.
    DSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Warning: Permanently added 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX' (DSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 516/1024
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f8e28500a10),
debug2: key: /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug3: start over, passed a different list password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

If I'm reading the output correctly (and I may not be) the handshake process settled on using `aes128-cbc` for key exchange and `hmac-md5` for the actual session encryption. According to [the JSCH documentation](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (minimal though it may be), both of these algorithms are supported.

I can connect to this share with both the `sftp` command-line utility and with FileZilla, so the problem has to either be with JSCH or with my Java configuration, but I'm at a loss to figure out what's what.

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

JSCH version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.51</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** It looks like [a bug for this exact behaviour](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921) was filed against the JDK, but was closed with no resolution. There's also [an email thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2014-September/011231.html) between the maintainers of JSCH and the JDK developers that discusses the issue, but has no resolution.

Comment: Wow. I popped in here to recommend JCE, but it looks like you've done your homework (not that that should have been the issue anyway, but all the same). Any chance you could try it with Oracle Java (instead of OpenJDK) 7? I don't mean to be vague, but I've had bad luck with OpenJDK in the past. At this point, I'd say Oracle Java would be worth trying at least. You may have to install JCE into it (I'm grasping at straws here admittedly. Just hoping I can help)

Comment: Some clarifications: (1) You didn't install JCE, that's already in the Java package. You installed the "Unlimited Strength Policy" which is an *addon to* JCE. That only makes a difference if the desired/negotiated symmetric encryption is over 128 bits, which it appears your case is not.
(2) Your sftp handshake selected `aes128-cbc` for *encryption* and `hmac-md5` for *integrity-checking*; key-exchange is Diffie-Hellman, host authentication is DSA, and client authentication appears to be password. ...

Comment: ... (3) The DH and DSA groups used appear to be 1024 bits, which should be okay for Java 7. But in case the debug output isn't exact and reliable, it might help to get a network trace especially of the jsch attempt with Wireshark or similar to make sure and see exactly when it fails. Or if you can test with Java 8, that expands the limits for DH and DSA (although you may or may not want 8 for other reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @dave_thompson_085. Can you tell me which step is complaining about the key being too long? The other SO post that I linked appears to suggest that the target server is using a DSA key length > 1024 bits. Is this key length unsupported by Java, or is there some configuration that I can do to allow it?

Comment: On checking further I was partly mistaken. Java7 limits DH and DSA *generation* to 1024, but that's a different exception than you have, and ssh handshake doesn't generate DSA (only use it).
Are you sure you're not running j8, or (somehow) j8 provider(s)? AFAICT this exception message does not exist at all in j7.
What I forgot is that SSH still uses SHA1 with DSA>1024 not the better-matched SHA224 and SHA256,
and it seems Java8 decided to block this combination. The bug report and emails you now point to make this explicit, and 
I agree it appears Oracle refuses to change. ...

Comment: ... (1) You might win by using a different provider for DSA signatures that doesn't enforce this check. BouncyCastle 1.46 allows the DSA operation by itself, but I haven't checked more recent versions, and sometimes giving BC preference breaks other things. (2) The patch in #25404371 (note: on inner class ...DSA.LegacyDSA) should work but is a bit ugly. (3) It would work to get the server to decrease to 1024 (but they shouldn't) or switch to RSA or ECDSA which do not have this problem (they might).

Comment: The problem started happening when we upgraded from Java 1.7.0.55 to Java 1.7.0.71. The new version appears to backport the key length requirement from Java 1.8.x.

Comment: It looks like enough people have complained about this issue that the Java developers have decided to remove the key length check from JDK9. 

I have no idea how long these things take to work their way through the release cycle and get in front of users.

Here's the original bug that was reported, now resolved with a 'Fixed' status:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921

Here's the diff of DSA.java that removes the key length check:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/edd7a67585a5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up swapping JSCH out for [SSHJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj). It depends on the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) crypto libraries rather than on Java's built-in crypto packages, and is capable of connecting to our server with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can force JSCH to use SHA256 instead of SHA1 with `keysize > 1024` (which JSSE doesn't allow anymore) like this:

```
java.util.Properties configuration = new java.util.Properties();
configuration.put("kex", "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256");           
configuration.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(configuration);
```

Comment: What does "JSSE doesn't allow anymore" refer to? Can you provide references?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the [bug for this behaviour](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921) that was filed against the JDK was not closed - the decision to close it was reverted and it has been *fixed* a few days later. It has later been backported, so *upgrading to [Java SE 8u45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (or higher) solves the issue* as well.

Answer (score -1):

Install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files [click here to download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

Replace local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar with unrestricted policy files at following location :
Java\jre7\lib\security\

I had similar problem while encryption of data with ibm jre version 1.5 and tomcat.

Comment: Please read the original post in full. We tried installing the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files, and that didn't help