# Jsch not working with certain sftp servers

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jsch, jce

This question is almost a copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557181/java-1-7-jsch-java-security-invalidkeyexception-key-is-too-long-for-this-alg). But since it went unresolved I want to ask if some other figured out the a work around with JSCH java library ??
The problem again is that I can connect to most of the SSH server using JSCH library but there seems to be this one server I've encountered that I cannot connect to using JSCH. While establishing a connection it throws out a exception stating :

```
INFO: Connecting to xxxx.xxxxx.com port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-2.0
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-dss
INFO: kex: server: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,cast128-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: aes128-cbc,rijndael128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,cast128-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: Disconnecting from xxxxx.xxxxx.com port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:558)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.test.filetransfer.SftpDownload.main(SftpDownload.java:29)
Exception occurred : Session.connect: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm
```

I already have installed the unlimited encryption policy but
it seems to be the problem with default Java JCE provider which supports DH and DSA generation to 1024 bits. This stack supports my claim :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect failed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:560)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:184)
    at com.test.filetransfer.SftpDownload.main(SftpDownload.java:28)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for this algorithm
    at sun.security.provider.DSA$LegacyDSA.checkKey(DSA.java:487)
    at sun.security.provider.DSA.engineInitVerify(DSA.java:152)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1124)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1087)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitVerify(Signature.java:1142)
    at java.security.Signature.initVerify(Signature.java:452)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.SignatureDSA.setPubKey(SignatureDSA.java:52)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyExchange.verify(KeyExchange.java:269)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.DHG1.next(DHG1.java:187)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:327)
```

I really don't want to ditch JSCH library due to it's rich feature,popularity and documentation and the server is out of our jurisdiction.

So is there a workaround anyone has figured out using JSCH library ???

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Thank you, i've enabled the logging now and edited the post with the verbose connection message, but cannot figure out the problem though !!!!

Comment: Can you find out a call stack of the `java.security.InvalidKeyException`? Place a breakpoint at `Session.java:558` and inspect the `e`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry cannot do that. By breakpoint you may mean as in  a IDE but I am deploying this code by building a jar in my cloud instance which has to be white-listed by the sftp server  which the clients own. If there is another way please do mention that ??

Comment: OK, so change `throw new JSchException("Session.connect: "+e)` to `throw new JSchException("Session.connect failed", e)`. So that all information about the inner exception/cause is preserved.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl done !!! i've pasted the stack above and it seems it's due to the DSA generator. Now what can we do ????

Comment: It looks like the server's DSA key is longer than 1024 bits. Java JCE provider is not the only library having trouble with those. Java 8 fixes this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html - and adds support for 2048-bit DSS keys (not sure whether keys >1024 but <2048 are supported). See this related post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557181/java-1-7-jsch-java-security-invalidkeyexception-key-is-too-long-for-this-alg

Comment: thanks but I've referred the link above while posting the question, it doesn't solve anything just provides an alternative library which  I'm trying to avoid at this point

Comment: Actually, the link above does provide a solution, although it's well hidden. It links to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921 which in turn reveals this bug has been fixed in Java SE 8u45. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, then this might be caused by a [bug in Java JCE](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921) that has recently been fixed. Upgrading to [Java SE 8u45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (or higher) solves the issue.

I verified that with 1.8.0_45, jsch-0.1.53 is actually able to successfully negotiate an SSH session with a server that uses a 1536-bit DSA key.